# How can iterate object value from json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I tried to implement small google map. I have a json object that is : {"app_title":"whether","users":{"iv001":{"lat":"17.85","lng":"18.45"}}}  . How can i iterate lat and lng values. please help me.

```
{ "app_title":"whether",
  "users": { 
     "iv001": {
             "lat":"17.85",
             "lng":"18.45"
       }
   }
 }
```

var latitude = ???; //here we need lat value
var longitude = ???; //here we need lng value

Comment: Can you try this `var latitude = data.users.iv001.lat` for latitude, One more thing `var data = {"app_title":"whether","users":{"iv001":{"lat":"17.85","lng":"18.45"}}}`

Comment: Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'iv001' of undefined  . occured

Comment: If there will always be a single user, then answer from @Dinesh should work, if there can be multiple users, as is apparent from the json provided, you could loop through the users and get lat and lng for each user. I can answer that if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use dot notation to access object value. `data.users.iv001.lat;` gives you lat.`data.users.iv001.lng;` gives you lng

```js
var data ={"app_title":"whether","users":{"iv001":{"lat":"17.85","lng":"18.45"}}};

var lat = data.users.iv001.lat;
var lag =data.users.iv001.lng;
console.log("Lat:"+lat,"Lag:"+lag);
```

OR like this `data.users["iv001"].lat;`

```js
var data ={"app_title":"whether","users":{"iv001":{"lat":"17.85","lng":"18.45"}}};

var lat = data.users["iv001"].lat;
var lag =data.users["iv001"].lng;
console.log("Lat:"+lat,"Lag:"+lag);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var testData = {"app_title":"whether","users":{"iv001":{"lat":"17.85","lng":"18.45"},"iv002":{"lat":"14.85","lng":"16.45"}}}

var arr = Object.values(testData.users);

for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
console.log('Long : ' + arr[i].lng + ', ' + 'Lat : ' + arr[i].lat);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yr47xgx3/

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = {"app_title":"whether","users":{"iv001":{"lat":"17.85","lng":"18.45"}}}
var latitude = obj.users.iv001.lat;
var longitude = obj.users.iv001.lng;
```

Comment: Thank you boss. I am getting values. if in case no. of id's is there. How can Make loop.  var obj = {"app_title":"whether","users":{"iv001":{"lat":"17.85","lng":"18.45"}, "iv002":{"lat":"12.85","lng":"13.45"}, "iv003":{"lat":"14.85","lng":"15.45"}}}.   ?????

Comment: @vinodhkumar
for (key in obj.users) {
 console.log(obj.users[key].lat);
 console.log(obj.users[key].lng);
}